# При попытке перехода из фрагмента в фрагмент вылазит ошибка (все это в адаптере recycler view)

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview.adapter

Возникла такая проблема: у меня есть адаптер для recycler view:

```
    class AdapterForClassesList(private val data: MutableList<String>,
                            private val fragmentManager: FragmentManager): RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterForClassesList.MyViewHolder>(){


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.example_for_classes_list, parent, false)

        //возвращаем этот элемент
        return MyViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
        holder.text_class.text = data[position]


        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_class_information, class_information()).commit()

        }


    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return data.size
    }

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var text_class: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.classes_number_text)
    }

}
```

Но при запуске ругается на `R.id.fragment_class_information`:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.teacherportal, PID: 8561
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0900da (com.example.teacherportal:id/fragment_class_information) for fragment class_information{4f369a3} (88c5eb20-9e5d-434a-b29e-5606bf6aa910 id=0x7f0900da)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:513)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Мне нужно понять что нужно изменить чтобы переход совершался корректно.
Спасибо за помощь, если нужно, пишите дополню чем нужно.

Изменено:
Вот разметка того самого fragment_class_information (это тот самый контейнер в который должен загрузиться фрагмент)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_class_information"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:tag="fragment_class_information"
    tools:context=".fragments.class_information">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_class"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
            android:text="7A"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_class" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: fragment_class_information - что это? По идее вы должны передавать ID контейнера для фрагментов. Возможно, вы не его передаёте. Покажите разметку где контейнер для фрагментов находится. Или вы не тот менеджер фрагментов используете. Они разные в активити и во фрагменте. Для этого покажите где и как вы создаёте адаптер - т.е. какой из менеджеров туда передаёте.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не очень понимаю что вы хотите чтобы я добавил:  

Они разные в активити и во фрагменте. Для этого покажите где и как вы создаёте адаптер - т.е. какой из менеджеров туда передаёте

Comment: Вы не то показываете, кажется) Фрагменты можно по разному отображать. Обычно - их отображают внутри активити, указывая в транзакции в какую втюху фрагмент поместить. Обычно это FrameLayout. Вы же, кажется, фрагмент куда-то не туда добавляете. Что такое `R.id.fragment_class_information` - это ведь, наверное, не контейнер в активити? И, наверное, даже не контейнер во врагменте? Вы используете фрагменты, вложенные во фрагменты? Это важно - надо выбирать тот или иной менеджер фрагментов. Адаптер у вас в активити или фрагменте?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Емае, я что-то затупил, просто не знал что контейнер должен быть в активити, а я указывал сам фрагмент. Спасибо вам большое, все работает и я теперь знаю чуть-чуть больше)